# how can i compare variable vs multi variables in if statement in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
  IF v_salary + p_value <
        ALL (v_max_salary, v_manager_salary, v_dept_salary)
  THEN
     UPDATE employees
        SET salary = salary + p_value
      WHERE employee_id = p_emp_id;
  END IF;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to compare it to each of those values separately - if it is true for the least of them, it is true for the rest of them as well. So:

```
IF v_salary + p_value < least(v_max_salary, v_manager_salary, v_dept_salary)
THEN
   UPDATE employees
      SET salary = salary + p_value
    WHERE employee_id = p_emp_id;
END IF;
```

Comment: or `...WHERE employee_id = p_emp_id AND v_salary + p_value < LEAST(v_max_salary, v_manager_salary, v_dept_salary)` without `if` statement